Flexbox behaviour, how do i make it so 2 of the boxes are next to eachother when resizing to mobile screens
When I resize the browser (trying to make it responsive for mobile) 3 of the boxes gets pushed down so there is one at the top and three below; I want them to be side by side two and two. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, I hope someone gets what I'm trying to say.
Do I need to use media query, or how should I go about this?
CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/v8rL4w1a/


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

/* Importerar typsnitt från Google Fonts, Raleway och Roboto med olika varianter. */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}


/* Deklarerar CSS-variabler för att lätt kunna ändra färger och storlekar på text och bakgrund. */

:root {
  --text-color: #fdfff5;
  --bg-color: #8c8453;
  --main-color: #1b1e10;
  --border-color: #677786;
  --h1-front: 5.5rem;
  --h2-front: 3rem;
  --p-font: 1.2rem;
}


/* Inställningar för body: färg och bakgrundsbild, där bilden täcker hela bakgrunden och stannar fast vid scroll. */

body {
  color: var(--text-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
  background-image: url("./image/golf.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Header är fixerat längst upp och täcker hela bredden. Innehållet placeras horisontellt med flexbox och en suddig bakgrund används. */

header {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Stil på logotypen: stor text, vit färg och fet stil. */

.logo {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Färgar all text inuti span-element med huvudfärgen. */

span {
  color: var(--main-color);
}


/* Flexbox-layout för navigeringsfältet (navbar) för horisontell placering av länkar. */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
}


/* Stil på navigeringslänkarna: vit text, fet stil, padding och rundade hörn. Smooth transition vid hover. */

.navbar a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: var(--p-font);
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Vid hover: bakgrunden ändras till en guldbrun färg. */

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #8d7014;
}


/* Flexbox för "följ oss"-sektionen med vertikal centrering. */

.follow-oss {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Första länken i "följ oss"-sektionen har en unik stil: guldbrun färg, fet stil, gräns och rundade hörn med mörk bakgrund. */

.follow-oss a:first-child {
  color: #8d7014;
  font-size: var(--p-font);
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}


/* Allmänna länkar i "följ oss"-sektionen: vit text, mellanstorlek och smooth transition vid hover. */

.follow-oss a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/* Vid hover på första länken: bakgrunden blir transparent och färgen. */

.follow-oss a:first-child:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #8c9ca3;
}


/* Vid hover på övriga länkar: textfärgen ändras till guldbrun. */

.follow-oss a:hover {
  color: #8d7014;
}


/* Centrerar ett element både vertikalt och horisontellt på sidan. */

.container {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808), rgba(138, 109, 50, 0.836), rgba(161, 124, 53, 0.719));
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
}

.shop {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  width: 34rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
}

.set {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 32rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #638c53;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.klubbor {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 32rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #638c53;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.cart {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.produkter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.produkter2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.produkt {
  background-color: #8c8453d5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.produkt:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.produkt img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #218838;
}

.dropbutton {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: -1rem;
  top: 2.3rem;
}

.dropcontent a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropcontent a:hover {
  background-color: #218838;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
  background-color: #638c53;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbutton {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 872px) {
  .container {
    width: 872px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 872px) {
  footer {
    width: 872px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 872px) {
  header,
  html {
    width: 872px;
  }
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="shop">Välkommen till våran shop</div>
    <div class="set">Golf set</div>
    <section class="produkter">
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/Golfset barn.png" alt="Produkt 1" />
        <h2>Golf-set Junior</h2>
        <p>749 kr</p>
        <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/Callaway golfset.png" alt="Produkt 2" />
        <h2>Callaway-XL</h2>
        <p>3400 kr</p>
        <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/X LZR womens set.webp" alt="Produkt 3" />
        <h2>X LZR Womens</h2>
        <p>2200 kr</p>
        <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/Callaway Pro mens.webp" alt="Produkt 4" />
        <h2>Callaway-Pro</h2>
        <p>5499 kr</p>
        <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="klubbor">Klubbor</div>
    <section class="produkter2">
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/Drivers.png" alt="Produkt 5" />
        <h2>Drivers</h2>
        <p>300-2500 kr</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
          <div class="dropcontent">
            <a href="#">Taylor Made Stealth 2</a>
            <a href="#">Ping G425 Max</a>
            <a href="#">Callaway Paradym</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/FAIRWAY WOODS.png" alt="Produkt 6" />
        <h2>Fairway woods</h2>
        <p>200-2000 kr</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
          <div class="dropcontent">
            <a href="#">Cobra Darkspeed X</a>
            <a href="#">Wilson Launch Pad 2</a>
            <a href="#">Srixon ZX</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/PUTTER.png" alt="Produkt 7" />
        <h2>Putters</h2>
        <p>250-1900 kr</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
          <div class="dropcontent">
            <a href="#">TaylorMade Spidertour X</a>
            <a href="#">Odyssey Elven Tour</a>
            <a href="#">Cleveland Frontline Iso</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="produkt">
        <img src="./image/WEDGAR.webp" alt="Produkt 8" />
        <h2>Wedgars</h2>
        <p>200-2400 kr</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
          <div class="dropcontent">
            <a href="#">Cleveland RTX6</a>
            <a href="#">Callaway Opus</a>
            <a href="#">Titleist SM10</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>



JS Fiddle demo.

Your issue can be resolved with multiple solution. First with flexbox by adding flex-wrap: wrap boxes will get rapped below if required space is not provided. Below is working example with flexbox.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.boxs {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
<h2 class="mainDiv">
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
</h2>



I will personally use second approach which is using grid as it gives more control because you can accurately specify how much box's needs to display according to screen size. For desktop screen you can use grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) which will adjust to 4 box's and for smaller screen with media query you can use grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) which will adjust to 2 box's.
Below is working example of that and if I have misunderstood or missed something then do share.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)
}

.boxs {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mainDiv {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
  }
}
<h2 class="mainDiv">
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
  <div class="boxs"></div>
</h2>



